# History.js -- strange behavior in IE... and Chrome not firing state change event on a pushState

Tags: javascript, ajax, history.js

I am SO ready to pull my hair out regarding History.js.   I'm trying to make it work so that the URLs it saves to its history actually match full query strings that I want folks to be able to use as bookmarks.   And then I'm using Javascript to snag that incoming query string and branch off to various other Javascript methods based on that data.

And I need it to work with IE 8 (yeah, I know...), Firefox and Chrome (more-up-to-date-versions).

Oh, and one more requirement:  The "default" / index page should actually automatically run an Ajax query (with default criteria) that ends up populating a table.

Well, at the end of two days, I thought I finally had everything working.  Incoming query strings would run the Javascript routines.  And within those routines, I'd have History.pushState calls to populate the history.  I had discovered that History.pushState would then cause the exact same Javascript method (and Ajax search) to run a SECOND time.  So, I instituted a little work-around found here:

https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/47#issuecomment-25750285

Everything was working, except that the History wouldn't "remember" my index page.  So, instead of having my Javascript that detects the query string fire a Javascript method, I instead told it to do a History.pushState to fire that method.

All seemed to be working well and I went to bed.

This morning, I said, geez, I'd better check Firefox.    Only to find that Firefox appears to not be doing anything, once it reaches that line that's supposed to fire the History.pushState for the index page.  No state change is firing.

I fired up IE8.   Odd.  It fires an "alert" message that apparently contains the contents of the parameters I am sending to History.pushState !  (Now, Chrome dumps this out to the console.log.   But this is not dumping out to IE's console. Hmmm...)   What's really odd is that the URL field in the browser is odd.  All of my URLs look like "domain.com/?search" or "domain.com/?whatever".    IE8 is showing me a URL for the index page of "/#./?&_suid=1405599 "

Doe anybody have History.js working.... on IE8 and other more modern browsers... using "fake" URLs that are actually "real" URLs, in the sense that the ones History.js uses are the same URLs whose query strings you act on to do stuff?

I get the feeling I should throw in the towel and... I think... start using Angular.js instead?    I just want to have get the "Back" and "Forward" buttons and "Bookmarks/Links" working.  Sheesh!

Comment: Ah, just found about the SUID on IE8 here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809935/history-js-plugin-how-to-use    Heh, just did that and now IE refuses to fire the state change as well. <sigh>

Comment: OK, I put that back.  I can live with SUID's since it seems everything's working as it should in terms of state changes.  And removing  'History.log()' from my code got rid of the strange IE pop-ups.    And, oddly enough, I can't explain why... Firefox is no longer halting where it was.